# Inequality : $\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{xyz}} + \sqrt{\frac{xy+yz+zx}{x^2+y^2+z^2}} \geq 1+\sqrt[3]{3}$

Tags: inequality, radicals, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, uvw

> Let $x>0$, $y>0$ and $z > 0$. Prove that $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{xyz}} + \sqrt{\frac{xy+yz+zx}{x^2+y^2+z^2}} \geq
> 1+\sqrt[3]{3}.$$

From Micheal Rozenberg's answer :

$(x+2)\sqrt{x^2+2}\left(\sqrt{x^2+2}+\sqrt{2x+1}\right)\geq\sqrt[3]x\left(\sqrt[3]{(x^3+2)^2}+\sqrt[3]{3x(x^3+2)}+\sqrt[3]{9x^2}\right)$,

Prove that $(x+2)^2(x+2\sqrt{x}+3)\geq9\sqrt[3]{x(x^3+2)^2}$,

LHS :

$(x+2)\sqrt{x^2+2}\left(\sqrt{x^2+2}+\sqrt{2x+1}\right)\geq (x+2) \frac{x+2}
{\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{2\sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)= \frac{(x+2)^2}{3}(x+2\sqrt{x}+3)$

RHS :

$\sqrt[3]{3x(x^3+2)}\leq \sqrt[3]{(x^3+2)^2}$

$\sqrt[3]{9x^2}\leq \sqrt[3]{(x^3+2)^2}$

so $\sqrt[3]{(x^3+2)^2}+\sqrt[3]{3x(x^3+2)}+\sqrt[3]{9x^2}\leq 3\sqrt[3]{(x^3+2)^2}$

$\sqrt[3]{x}(\sqrt[3]{(x^3+2)^2}+\sqrt[3]{3x(x^3+2)}+\sqrt[3]{9x^2})\leq 3\sqrt[3]{x(x^3+2)^2}$

Thus,

$\frac{(x+2)^2}{3}(x+2\sqrt{x}+3) \geq 3\sqrt[3]{x(x^3+2)^2}$

$(x+2)^2(x+2\sqrt{x}+3) \geq 9\sqrt[3]{x(x^3+2)^2}$

Comment: yuck..................

Comment: @carat I gave a solution. You may check it if you are interested in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$ and $xyz=w^3$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{27u^2-27uv^2}{w^3}+3}+\sqrt{\frac{v^2}{3u^2-2v^2}}\geq1+\sqrt[3]3,$$
which is $f(w^3)\geq0,$ where $f$ is a decreasing function.

Thus, it's enough to prove our inequality for a maximal value of $w^3$.

Now, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positive roots of the following equation.
$$(X-x)(X-y)(X-z)=0$$ or
$$X^3-3uX^2+3v^2X-w^3=0$$ or
$$X^3-3uX^2+3v^2X=w^3,$$
which says that the graph of $f(X)= X^3-3uX^2+3v^2X$ and the line $Y=w^3$

have three common points $(x,f(x))$, $(y,f(y))$ and $(z,f(z)).$

Now, draw the graph of $f$.

Indeed, $f(X)= X^3-3uX^2+3v^2X$, which gives $$f'(X)=3X^2-6uX+3v^2=3(X^2-2uX+v^2)=$$
$$=3\left(X-(u+\sqrt{u^2-v^2})\right)\left(X-(u-\sqrt{u^2-v^2})\right).$$

Thus, $X_{max}=u-\sqrt{u^2-v^2}$, $X_{min}=u+\sqrt{u^2-v^2}$

and the graph of $f$  goes through origin $(0,0)$.

Draw it, please!

Let $z\leq y\leq x$, $u$ and $v^2$ be constants and $w^3$ increases.

Hence, $x$, $y$ and $z$ changes and $w^3$ will get a maximal value,

when a line $Y=w^3$ will touch to the graph of $f$ in the maximum point of $f$,

which happens for equality case of two variables (when $z=y=u-\sqrt{u^2-v^2}$ in our case).

Since our inequality is homogeneous, we can assume $y=z=1$ and we need to prove that
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^3+2}{x}}+\sqrt{\frac{2x+1}{x^2+2}}\geq1+\sqrt[3]3$$ or
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^3+2}{x}}-\sqrt[3]3\geq1-\sqrt{\frac{2x+1}{x^2+2}}$$ or
$$\frac{x^3-3x+2}{\sqrt[3]x\left(\sqrt[3]{(x^3+2)^2}+\sqrt[3]{3x(x^3+2)}+\sqrt[3]{9x^2}\right)}\geq\frac{x^2-2x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+2}\left(\sqrt{x^2+2}+\sqrt{2x+1}\right)}$$ or
$$(x+2)\sqrt{x^2+2}\left(\sqrt{x^2+2}+\sqrt{2x+1}\right)\geq\sqrt[3]x\left(\sqrt[3]{(x^3+2)^2}+\sqrt[3]{3x(x^3+2)}+\sqrt[3]{9x^2}\right).$$
Now, by C-S we obtain
$$\sqrt{x^2+2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\sqrt{(1+2)(x^2+2)}\geq\frac{x+2}{\sqrt3}$$ and
$$\sqrt{2x+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\sqrt{(2+1)(2x+1)}\geq\frac{2\sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt3}.$$
Also, by AM-GM
$$3x\leq x^3+2.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$(x+2)^2(x+2\sqrt{x}+3)\geq9\sqrt[3]{x(x^3+2)^2}$$ or
$$(a^2+2)^2(a^2+2a+3)\geq9\sqrt[3]{a^2(a^6+2)^2},\tag1$$
where $a=\sqrt{x}$ and the rest is smooth.

The last inequality follows from the following inequalities.
$$(a^2+2)^5\geq54a(a^6+2)$$ and
$$2(a^2+2)(a^2+2a+3)^3\geq27a(a^6+2).$$
Done!

Comment: I've learnt uvw method the first time from this problem. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @carat You are welcome!

Comment: How do you think of decomposing Inequality (1) into the last two inequalities? How do you prove the last two inequalities?

Comment: @Hans It's not so easy, but I am ready to show.

Comment: Are you in the process of writing up the derivation? Thanks, Micheal.

Comment: @Hans The second inequality is obvious. For the first: $(a^2+2)^5-54a(a^6+2)=(a^5-a^3-5a^2-4a+3)^2+(12a^2-44a+41)a^6+(6a^2-16a+11)a^4+(36a^2-34a+9)a^2+85a^2-84a+23>0$.

Comment: I really want to know how you come up with the amazing expression in your last comment. Could you please reveal your trick? :-)  The second inequality is not obvious to the obtuse me. :-P Please elucidate. Many thanks, Michael. My dumb method to prove Inequality (1) is to cube the inequality, substitute $a=b+1$, expand out all powers, move everything to the left and see all power coefficients are positive.

Comment: @Hans If $a=b+1$ then $b$ can be negative. For the second inequality we have: $2(a^2+2)(a^2+2a+3)^3-27a(a^6+2)>2a^8-15a^7+46a^6>0$. Since the coefficient before $a$ in $2(a^2+2)(a^2+2a+3)^3$ greater than $54$, it's enough to calculate coefficients before $a^7$ and before $a^6$, which is easy.

Comment: Right for the second inequality! Regarding my proof of Inequality (1), $a\ge1$ as $1=z=y\le x$, so $b\ge0$ not negative.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to elucidate how you come up with your expression in the proof for the first inequality?

Comment: @Hans I tried, tried else and it turned out! Firstly, I want to delete $a^{10}$ and the rest is just playing  with coefficients in $a^5+Aa^3+Ba^2+Ca+D$,

Comment: My alternative dumb, but direct proof of Inequality (1) is $(a^2+2)^6(a^2+2a+3)^3-9^3a^2(a^6+2)^2=a^{18} + 6 a^{17} + 33 a^{16} + 2a^{13}(58 a^2 - 177 a + 471) + 2203 a^{12} + 4248 a^{11} + 7704 a^{10} + 11720 a^9 + 14016 a^8 + 20352 a^7 + 23536 a^6 + 21792 a^5 + 19920 a^4 + 13184 a^3 + 6300 a^2 + 3456 a + 1728>0$ $\forall a\ge 0$ since the determinant of the quadratic polynomial in the parathesis is negative and all other coefficients are positive.

Comment: @Hans Yes of course, but the degree is $18$ and it's a bit of harder, I think.

Comment: But the only hard part for this proof is expanding the polynomial which is just labor.

Comment: @Hans You are right! I just looked for a nice proof and I did not find.

Comment: Good that we agree. Do you mind we put all these proof into your wonderful answer so as to make it more detailed and complete for later reference and for other people to understand your answer better?

Comment: @Hans I also think so.

Answer (score 3):

$$x+y+z=p,\ xy+yz+zx=q,\ xyz=r$$

we can assume :  $x+y+z=1$

$x^3+y^3+z^3=1-3q+3r,\ x^2+y^2+z^2=1-2q\ \ \ \left( 0 < q \le \dfrac{1}{3}\right)$

$$\left( \dfrac{1-3q}{r}+3\right)^{1/3}+\left( \dfrac{q}{1-2q}\right)^{1/2}\ge 1+\sqrt[3]3$$
We have
$$q^2=(xy+yz+zx)^2\ge 3xyz(x+y+z) =3r.$$

So: $LHS \ge \sqrt[3]3\cdot\left( \dfrac{1-3q}{q^2}+1\right)^{1/3}+\left( \dfrac{q}{1-2q}\right)^{1/2}=f(q)$

$$\dfrac{q}{1-2q}=t  \le 1$$

$g(t)= \sqrt[3]3\cdot\left( \dfrac{1+t}{t^2}-1\right)^{1/3}+ \sqrt{t}\ge  g\left(1\right )=1+\sqrt[3]3$

Comment: I think a proof that $f$ decrease is not so easy.

Comment: Yes, it is terrible function, but only one variable )))

Comment: But indeed, it decreases. +1.

Comment: Do you mean to say just $q^2\ge 3r$? Both $q\ge 3p$ and $pq=r$ are wrong. Take $x=y=z=\frac13$.

Comment: @Hans It means $(xy+xz+yz)^2\geq3xyz(x+y+z)$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: That is exactly what I am saying by my first question. I am saying THAT relation is right and that is what you need and his other two relationships are wrong. You do not need them any way.

Comment: @Hans Yes, it was a typo. I fixed it. See now, please.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I see the other change but not the offending inequality. Maybe your fix is awaiting review...

Comment: @Hans There is a factor $\sqrt[3]3$. It's good now.

Comment: But still $q\ge 3p$ and $pq=r$ are wrong. We should delete those. I am doing it now.

Comment: I'm edit my solution))

Comment: Could you please demonstrate $g(t)$ decreases?

Comment: Thank you, Sergic Primazon.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Do you know how to prove $g(t)$ decreases?

Comment: @Hans Yes, but my proof is very ugly.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Could you please show your proof, ugly or not, in a new answer? Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I have put up in the form of an answer below my direct proof that $g(t)$ decreases for $t\in(0,1]$. Take a look.

Answer (score 2):

A proof by using the Sergic Primazon's idea. Dedicated to dear Hans.

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$ and $xyz=w^3$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{27u^3-27uv^2}{w^3}+3}+\sqrt{\frac{v^2}{3u^2-2v^2}}\geq\sqrt[3]3+1.$$
Now, since $27u^3-27uv^2\geq0$ and $v^4\geq uw^3$, it's enough to prove that
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{27u^4-27u^2v^2}{v^4}+3}+\sqrt{\frac{v^2}{3u^2-2v^2}}\geq\sqrt[3]3+1.$$
Let $3u^2-2v^2=p^2v^2$, where $p>0$.

Thus, $p\geq1$, $u^2=\frac{p^2+2}{3}v^2$ and we need to prove that
$$\sqrt[3]{3(p^2+2)^2-9(p^2+2)+3}+\frac{1}{p}\geq1+\sqrt[3]3$$ or
$$\sqrt[3]3\left(\sqrt[3]{p^4+p^2-1}-1\right)\geq\frac{p-1}{p}$$ or
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}(p^4+p^2-2)}{\sqrt[3]{(p^4+p^2-1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{p^4+p^2-1}+1}\geq\frac{p-1}{p}$$ or
$$\sqrt[3]3p(p+1)(p^2+2)\geq\sqrt[3]{(p^4+p^2-1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{p^4+p^2-1}+1$$ and since
$$1\leq\sqrt[3]{p^4+p^2-1},$$ it's enough to prove that
$$\sqrt[3]3p(p+1)(p^2+2)\geq3\sqrt[3]{(p^4+p^2-1)^2}$$ or
$$p^3(p+1)^3(p^2+2)^3\geq9(p^4+p^2-1)^2$$ or
$$p^{12}+3p^{11}+9p^{10}+19p^9+21p^8+42p^7+26p^6+36p^5+33p^4+8p^3+18p^2-9\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: +1. Brilliant as usual! And thank you for your most generous dedication, Michael, hahahaa!

Comment: @Hans You are welcome!

Comment: Michael, could I possibly interest you in examining this inequality https://math.stackexchange.com/q/526050/64809? It is a tough one and has a bounty of 100. Thank you.

Comment: @Hans I thought about this inequality. I still don't see a proof.

Comment: OK. No worries, so long as you keep it simmering on your back burner. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my, as Michael Rozenberg rightly dubs it, ugly proof of the last step in Sergic Primazon's proof that is $g(t)$ decreases for $t\in(0,1]$.
$$g'(t) = -3^{-\frac23}\Big(\frac1{t^2}+\frac1t-1\Big)^{-\frac23}\Big(\frac2{t^3}+\frac1{t^2}\Big)+\frac12\Big(\frac1t\Big)^{\frac12}\ .$$
We want to show $g'(t)<0$ or 
$$3^{\frac23}\Big(\frac1t\Big)^{\frac12}\Big(\frac1{t^2}+\frac1t-1\Big)^{\frac23} < 2\Big(\frac2{t^3}+\frac1{t^2}\Big). $$

Let $s:=\frac1t-1\in[0,\infty)$. The above inequality is equivalent to it being raised to the power of $6$, because it is easy to see its both sides are positive after making the substitution of $t$ by $s$. The transformed inequality is
$$2^6(s+1)^9(2s+3)^6-3^4((1+s)^2+s)^4>0 \tag1$$
The left hand side of the above inequality is
$$4096 s^{15} + 73728 s^{14} + 617472 s^{13} + 3191808 s^{12} + 11388672 s^{11} + 29712384 s^{10} + 58555200 s^9 + 88764399 s^8 + 104358708 s^7 + 95156902 s^6 + 66743280 s^5 + 35363277 s^4 + 13701744 s^3 + 3665574 s^2 + 605556 s + 46575 $$
All the coefficients of the polynomial are positive, so Inequality (1) holds for $s\ge 0$ implying $g'(t)<0$ for $t\in(0,1]$.

Comment: It's terrible ugly, but it's proof.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Yes, it is ugly for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $u = \frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{3xyz}$ and $v = \frac{xy+yz+zx}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.
Then $u\ge 1$ and $0 \le v \le 1$.

We need to prove that $\sqrt[3]{3u} + \sqrt{v} \ge 1 + \sqrt[3]{3}$ or
$\sqrt[3]{3u} - \sqrt[3]{3} \ge 1 - \sqrt{v}$ or
$$\frac{3u - 3}{3^{2/3}(u^{2/3} + u^{1/3} + 1)} \ge \frac{1 - v}{1 + \sqrt{v}}.$$
By using $(w^3+1) - (w^2+w) = (w+1)(w-1)^2\ge 0$ for $w\ge 0$, we have
$u^{2/3} + u^{1/3} \le u + 1$ (simply letting $w = u^{1/3}$). Also, $3^{2/3} < 3$ and $\frac{1 - v}{1 + \sqrt{v}} \le 1 - v$.

It suffices to prove that
$\frac{3u-3}{3(u+2)} \ge 1 - v$
or $\frac{u-1}{u+2}\ge 1 - v$ or
$$\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3 - 3xyz}{x^3+y^3+z^3+6xyz} \ge \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx}{x^2+y^2+z^2}.$$
Since $x^3+y^3+z^3 - 3xyz = (x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2 - xy - yz - zx)$, the above inequality is written as
$$\frac{(x^2y+y^2z+z^2x+xy^2+yz^2+zx^2 - 6xyz)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)}{(x^3+y^3+z^3+6xyz)(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \ge 0.$$
By AM-GM, this inequality is true. We are done.